# Is there an elementary proof for preserving inequalities under the change of l_p metrics?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, fa.functional-analysis

Here is what I mean exactly:

Let $A=(a_1,a_2)$ and $B=(b_1,b_2)$ be two points in the real plane (for simplicity, but general finite dimensions would also be nice), and define the $\ell_p$-metric as $\|A\|_p=(|a_1|^p+|a_2|^p)^{1/p}$ for $1\leq p<\infty$ and set $\|A\|_\infty=\max(a_1,a_2)$.

What I want to prove (as part of a more general statement) is that if $\|A\|_{p_1}<\|B\|_{p_1}$ and $\|A\|_{p_2}<\|B\|_{p_2}$ for some $1 \leq p_1 < p_2 \leq \infty$, then $\|A\|_q<\|B\|_q$ for any $p_1\leq q\leq p_2$.

---

I have a proof using interpolation theory, more specifically the Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem, by defining a linear operator $T$ with $T(B)=A$. I can elaborate on this proof if someone is interested in it, but it seems to me like there should be a simpler way to show this, as this theorem talks about much more general spaces.

I wasn't able to find anything about this question in the literature, but maybe I just don't know the right keywords. My background is more in discrete mathematics, so it is possible I'm just overlooking something obvious here, but I asked some people in functional analysis and they also (offhand) didn't know a simpler way.

Comment: l and p - and I thought this was number theory!

Comment: I'm sorry if my title was misleading! This is the setting I encountered the question. If you have an idea for a better title I'm all for it!

Comment: Show $\|A\|_p/\|B\|_p$ is a monotonic function of $p$.  For this two-dimensional case, it is a calculus exercise.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds very good! I will try to work it out this way!

Comment: Okay, I was able to show the original statement for the case $p_1=1$ and $p_2=\infty$, which was the minimal statement I needed. Apparently I should stick to combinatorics as I seem to perform poorly when it comes to calculus exercises. :) Thanks again to everyone helping me to figure this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality is not true in higher dimensions.
For instance, let $A$ have two components equal to 1/2 and 200 components eqaul to 1/100, and the rest zeros, and let $B$ have ten components equal to 1/4 and the rest zeros.
We compute
$$\|A\|_1=3,\|B\|_1=5/2,\|A\|_2=0.7211,\|B\|_2=0.7906,\|A\|_3=0.6301,\|B\|_3=0.5386.$$
Hence
$$\|A\|_1>\|B\|_1, \|A\|_3>\|B\|_3,$$
but 
$$\|A\|_2<\|B\|_2.$$

Comment: Thank you! This is interesting. Do you know if this can already happen in dimension 3? I now got the impression this might be case...

Comment: Yes, it can already happen in dimension 3. Indeed, your statement implies that if $\|A\|_{p_i} = \|B\|_{p_i}$ for $i=1,2$, then $\|A\|_{p} = \|B\|_{p}$ for all $p_1<p<p_2$. And $A=(1,1,0)$, $B=(1,1/2,1/2)$ gives a counterexample for $p_1=1,p_2=\infty$.